# How do I get Alexa Voice Service registration code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-voice-service

How do I get a registration code or otherwise solve this problem?

While writing this question, I realized the crux of this problem is the bottom-most part of this question: I'm not getting the popup I'm supposed to get and when I enter the URL in a browser it says invalid registration code.

I'm attempting to develop an Alexa Voice Service application.  Website/companion service only.  I have gone through the [Reference Implementation Guide](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/reference-implementation-guide) twice and have double checked that all of the setup has been done correctly.

This is the server error I get: invalid registration code.  I never did anything with a registration code and can't seem to find anything about a registration code (relevant to Alexa) anywhere after googling quite a bit.

`Listening on port 3000
error:  { [InvalidRegistrationCode: The provided registration code was invalid.]
  name: 'InvalidRegistrationCode',
  message: 'The provided registration code was invalid.',
  status: 401 }
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Here's the client output:

```
vlcj: (DefaultMediaPlayer.java:183)        
addMediaPlayerEventListener(listener=com.amazon.alexa.avs.AVSAudioPlayer$1@4b3a4950)
There was a problem connecting to the Companion Service. Trying again         in 2 seconds. Please make sure it is up and running. 
[DEBUG] joining on thread Thread[Timer-0,5,com.amazon.alexa.avs.AVSApp]
There was a problem connecting to the Companion Service. 
Trying again in 2 seconds. Please make sure it is up and running.
```

The AVS launcher opens too, and when I record something and send it I get:

```
com.amazon.alexa.avs.AVSException: 403 Invalid Access Token
```

The instructions mention (at the very bottom of the reference guide) that I need to:
    *Please register your device by visiting the following website on any system and following the instructions*:     https://localhost:3000/provision/************** That URL is supposed to pop something up once the companion service but that hasn't happened.

Any thoughts on how can I fix this?

Comment: Hi is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 2):

I was following a good document Project: Raspberry Pi + Alexa Voice Service  at https://github.com/amzn/alexa-avs-raspberry-pi . It describes all steps very well.
Please take a look at the following steps:

```
3 - Getting started with Alexa Voice Service
3.1 Register for a free Amazon Developer Account
3.4 Register your product and create a security profile.
6 - Enable Security Profile
```

Answer (score 1):

This thread on the Amazon developer forums seems related: http://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=11327&tstart=0

Quoted response:

> There are a number of potential issues causing that error.
>
> You might be sending an invalid scope. Are you sending "alexa:all" as
>   the scope? Or, your security profile might not be correctly linked. Is
>   it selected in the dropdown on the developer portal?
>
> Are you getting an access token from the companion service, or is the
>   text box blank? If you're not getting an access token, check that your
>   device serial number matches between the companion service and the
>   java client. If you're getting an access token, the problem is more
>   likely with your security profile.
>
> You should also look at these threads to see if they're helpful...
>   (links removed due to reputation requirement)

If that doesn't help, you'll probably have more luck asking the AVS team directly on their forum site.